# CSS Transform Scale not working in Chrome, Safari

Tags: google-chrome, css, safari, transform, scale

I have looked at different answers posted on here but nothing has worked for me...

What: I have a div that is scaled down to 0.6 and when called should scale up to 1 (100%).

Problem: In Firefox #myDiv is scaling up as intended, but nothing happens in Chrome or Safari (on mac).

I have this DIV code:

```
#myDiv {
-moz-animation: changeSize 1s ease-out .5s  forwards; /* Fx 5+ */
-webkit-animation: changeSize 1s ease-out .5s 0 forwards; /* Safari 4+ */
-o-animation: changeSize 1s ease-out .5s  forwards;  /* Opera */ 

-webkit-transform: scale(0.6);/* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
-moz-transform: scale(0.6); /* FF3.5+ */
-ms-transform: scale(0.6); /* IE9 */
-o-transform: scale(0.6); /* Opera 10.5+ */
transform: scale(0.6);

display: inline-block;
opacity:100;
background-image: url(img.png);
width: 154px;
height: 28px;
position: absolute;
left: 145px;
top: 5px;
}
```

And the keyframe animation for the scale up transition:

```
@keyframes changeSize {
0% {transform:scale(0.6)}
100% {transform: scale(1)}
}


@-moz-keyframes changeSize  /* Firefox */ {
0% {transform:scale(0.6)}
100% {transform:scale(1)}
}

@-webkit-keyframes changeSize  /* Safari and Chrome */{
0% {transform:scale(0.6)}
100% {transform:scale(1)}
}

@-o-keyframes changeSize  /* Opera */ {
0% {transform:scale(0.6)}
100% {transform:scale(1)}
}
```

The HTML:

Please advise what I am missing here!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your error is in this line :

```
-webkit-animation: changeSize 1s ease-out .5s 0 forwards;
```

There is an unnecessary `0`!

Lastly,

```
@-moz-keyframes changeSize  /* Firefox */ {
    0% {transform:scale(0.6)}
    100% {transform:scale(1)}
}

@-webkit-keyframes changeSize  /* Safari and Chrome */{
    0% {transform:scale(0.6)}
    100% {transform:scale(1)}
}

@-o-keyframes changeSize  /* Opera */ {
    0% {transform:scale(0.6)}
    100% {transform:scale(1)}
}
```

Within these keyframes, you're missing something. None of the transform property have **browser support prefixes.** For example:

```
@-webkit-keyframes changeSize  /* Safari and Chrome */{
    0% {-webkit-transform:scale(0.6)}
    100% {**-webkit-**transform:scale(1)}
}
```

I added -webkit- prefix to the transform property now it will display in Google Chrome and Safari.

Side note: you might have some unnecessary code blocks. -moz-,-ms-, and -o-.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just so you know, we prefer it when folks [don't append links or signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) to posts around here. If you'd like, you can add a link to your website to your user profile instead. Thanks again!